# Unable to locate the search box element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I want to locate the search box to input values and hit search using selenium python.

Below are the ways I tried to locate the element but nothing worked.

```py
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'location-search-form__input')
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="text"].location-search-form__input')
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="location-search"]')
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="location-search"]')
```

Below is the link to the website

Stridefitness - https://www.stridefitness.com/location-search

Below is the image of the website

[image: Locate the searchbox]

Comment: Once that website changes this quesiton as is is useless to future readers, it's therefore not a good fit for Stack Overflow, please include a [mre] of the pages sources alongside your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have trouble in finding element you can use xPath finder extension. For your specific case which I used, this is the xPath that worked.

```py
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/span/div/div[1]/div/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[1]/input')
```

Comment: Woah. It worked. Thanks a lot @Ali Ent.